Find a function which is not absolutely integrable but is the sum of absolutely integrable functions
The exercise asks me to show an example of functions $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $ |f(x)|, |g(x)|$ are integrable on the interval $[a,b]$, but $|f(x)+g(x)|$ is not integrable on that interval. 
I know the function $h:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}; h(x) = (-1)^nn$ for $\frac{1}{n+1}< x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ is not absolutely integrable (it's the example the book uses of an integrable function which is not absolutely so), and I wanted to try to find absolutely integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f + g = h$, but haven't been able to; any ideas?

I'm guessing you're talking about Riemann integrability, and not Lebesgue integrability? In the latter case it would be impossible due to the triangle inequality. Even in the Riemann case, the same triangle inequality tells you that you will need a lack of integrability rather than an infinite integral for your example to work.

Reimann integrability asssumed.
Since $~f(x),g(x) ~\text{integrable} \implies [ ~f(x) + g(x) ~] ~\text{integrable},~$ the requested example is forced to utilize that absolute values are involved.
Suppose that you define $~f(x)~$ as

$~f(x) = 1 ~: ~x ~$ is rational

$~f(x) = -1 ~: ~x ~$ is irrational.


Similarly, suppose that you define $~g(x)~$ as

$~g(x) = 2 ~: ~x ~$ is rational

$~g(x) = 2 ~: ~x ~$ is irrational.


Then, both $~| ~f(x) ~| ~$ and $~| ~g(x) ~| ~$ are integrable.
Further, the function $~| ~f(x) + g(x) ~| ~$ will evaluate to

$3~ ~: ~x ~$ is rational

$1~ ~: ~x ~$ is irrational.


So, the function $~| ~f(x) + g(x) ~| ~$ is not integrable.

Oh, that was rather on the nose.... Thank you!!
